# Multiple sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create a multiple table in single database. But I get such error from logcat: no such table. Below is my code.

```
private static final String DB_NAME = "MyPlayer";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "playerTable";
public static final String PlayerName = "name";
public static final String PlayerAge = "age";
public static final String PlayerBorn = "born";
public static final String PlayerWeight = "weight";
public static final String PlayerHeight = "height";

//test
public static final String TABLE_ATTACK = "attackTable";
public static final String AttackID = "aid";
public static final String Attack = "attack";
//test

public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Create a database table

            String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
                    + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement," + PlayerName + ", "
                    + PlayerAge + ", "+PlayerBorn+", "+PlayerWeight+", "+PlayerHeight+",);";
            db.execSQL(createQuery);

            String createQueryA = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_ATTACK + "(aid integer primart key, "+Attack+",);";//test 
            db.execSQL(createQueryA);//test
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ATTACK);//test
    onCreate(db);

}
```

Comment: In the first create query, there is an extra comma(`,`) in the end, and in the second `primart` should be `primary` ? Also Please post your LogCat errors, that would be helpful to identify the problem.

Comment: Also other than id columns you haven't specified datatype for any other columns.

Comment: @ShashankKadne, Thanks a lot. But i still get the error. here is the Logcat:

Comment: E/SQLiteLog(2052): (1) no such table: attackTable
E/SQLiteDatabase(2052): Error inserting attack=12 aid=11
E/SQLiteDatabase(2052): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: attackTable (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO attackTable(attack,aid) VALUES (?,?)
E/SQLiteDatabase(2052):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)

Comment: Your tables are not getting created. Log the create query string before executing the queries. Also paste the log output here with the updated queries.

Comment: I have a question here. is the code below create a table?
String createQueryA = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_ATTACK + "(aid integer primary key, "+Attack+");";
db.execSQL(createQueryA);


what you mean create query string?

Comment: BTW, i have 2 table and the first one is no problem, but second one getting the error. i do check with the coding, they are same...but why the second one keep getting error?@ShashankKadne

Comment: Should also be a leading space for column parameters in second query `" (aid integer primary key, "+Attack+");"`

Comment: or trailing space in this `String createQueryA = "CREATE TABLE "`

Comment: Thank you for helping me, guys! the problem is solved. the solution is uninstall the app from the emulator and install again, second table will be created!